# Azure automation - how public webhook to run a script?

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have a VM that i'd like to be able to turn on/off.
I have an automation script that starts the VM, and another that stops it.

What i'd like is to be able to, from a hosted webpage, click a button to 'start' it and one to 'stop' it.

Doesn't need to be super secure, as the page will be behind a password.

How would I go about doing that?  Just super easy - 'start' and 'stop'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use ajax on the webpage to do that, something like this:

```
function triggerWebhook() {
    var _url = 'https://s2events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=my_token_here';
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: _url
    })
};
```

and then add an event to the button to push it: `triggerWebhook()`

You could create 2 webhooks, one for start, one for stop. or a single webhook to toggle vm state.

Comment: You can create webhook on each job directly from Azure Automation. https://i.imgur.com/3Aeh8VN.png

Comment: Thanks!  So would I just be able to call that URL (to the webhook)?

Comment: well, you first need to create a webhook and then just call it with ajax (for example)